# how to update field in codeigniter ia using simple php working fine please check its

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update blank data in field like otp and otpvalidate condition best match current date after update but no idea in codeigniter please shere this idea. i want set header allawas check .

**simple code in php but i want to chaing codeigniter**

```
$currentdate = date('Y-m-d');

$sql="UPDATE login set otp ='', otpvalidate='' where otpvalidate='$currentdate'";

$t_result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
```

**Main (controller page )**

```
  public function otpdate()
         {
            $otpvalidate = date('Y-m-d'); 
            $this->load->model('login_model'); 
            $this->login_model->check($otpvalidate);
         }
```

**Login_model**

```
public function check($otpvalidate) { 
         $currentdate = date('Y-m-d');
         $this->db->where('otpvalidate', $currentdate)->update('login', array('otp' => '', 'otpvalidate' => ''));

        }
```

**but not working**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet can be used to find and update the db.

```
$currentdate = date('Y-m-d');
$this->db->where('otpvalidate', $currentdate)->update('login', array('otp' => '', 'otpvalidate' => ''));
```